GIT LFS - get file from repository
I am using curl command with private token and url to download a file from remote repository.
For example such way:
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-123abc" "http://car.wg:8100/api/v4/projects/67/repository/files/v001%2F20220531.tar.gz/raw?ref=master" --output 20220531.tar.gz
The file content looks like this:
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1 oid sha256:16c15c7dfd9fe14c6cb59a4badfa82bad104243e5653da74382e526dbc6b33f0 size 729067887
How can I get whole content and not just a pointer to the file?

git lfs install && git pull

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-lfs%5D+download+file
